# Cannot cast lambda expression to event handler

Tags: java, lambda, wildfly

I have a servlet running in a WildFly 10.0.0.CR5 container. I'm sending a POST request containing a `SOAPMessage` to the servlet, which is validated within the servlet:

```
private void unmarshalXmlMsg(final Node node, final JAXBContext jaxbContext, final URL resourceUrl) {
    try {
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(resourceUrl);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(e -> false);

        Object unmarshalledObj;
        String localName = node.getLocalName();
        String classpath = CLASS_MAP.get(localName);
        if (classpath == null) {
            unmarshalledObj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(node);
        } else {
            unmarshalledObj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(node, Class.forName(classpath));
        }

        if (unmarshalledObj instanceof JAXBElement<?>) {
            routeMessage((JAXBElement<?>) unmarshalledObj);
        }
    } catch (JAXBException | SAXException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("Error unmarshalling xml from body of soapMessage", e);
    }
}
```

Everything comes in fine, but when it reaches `unmarshaller.setEventHandler(e -> false);`, I get the following `Exception`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
com.lmco.spacefence.incoming.service.IncomingMessageServlet$$Lambda$154/468475414
to javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler
```

Changing it to the following fixes the error, and everything else executes fine:

```
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent arg0) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I know that  `e -> false` is valid in this case, but I'm not sure why it isn't working in the WildFly container. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** I should also note that the above `Exception` is caused by this:

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception
```

**EDIT:** I also checked `java -version` and `javac -version`, and both are 1.8.0_05. I tried creating an `Unmarshaller` and setting the event handler the same way in my client code before sending it to the servlet, and it worked fine. This leads me to believe that it's an issue within WildFly...but I'm not sure where to go from here. Please help!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Hi I don't think that ValidationEventHandler and Unmarshaller as expected to work  accepting  a functional interface \ λ expression.I tried to have a look on the jar api and the specific implementation. jaxb-2.2.x

Comment: Why wouldn't it accept a lambda expression? The method takes in a `ValidationEventHandler`, which is a functional interface, right? Could you link to something that shows why you think otherwise?